# Use github actions to concat json files

Tags: json, github, github-actions

I have a directory containing json files, and i want to use github actions to create a new file in the repository, that contains an array of all those json files.
for example, the directory `<my-repo>/configurations` contain the files `a.json`, `b.json`, I want to create a new file called `configs.json` contains `[<a.json content>,<b.json content>]`.
The creation must be done dynamically.
Any suggestions?

Comment: It something very specific, and I don't think there is an action on the marketplace that perform this operation today (after some research at least, I didn't find any). However, that means it's also an opportunity to create something nobody has done until now and share it with the community! So my suggestion would be to create a script that perform this operation and transform it into an action.

Answer (score 0):

solution for config files sitting under `\configs` directory:

```
name: build unified config file
on: [push]
jobs:
  build_file:
    name: build unified config file
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
      - name: Run script
        uses: jannekem/run-python-script-action@v1
        with:
          script: |
            import os, json, shutil
            with open("unified.json", "r+") as t:
              t.truncate(0)
              t.write('[')
              for filename in os.scandir('configs'):
                print(filename)
                with open(filename, "r") as f:
                  content = f.read()
                  t.write(content)
                  t.write(',')
              t.write(']')
            barak = open("unified.json", "r+")
            contentb = barak.read()
            print(contentb)
      - name: push file to main
        uses: EndBug/add-and-commit@v9
        with:
          add: 'unified.json'
          committer_name: Committer Name
          committer_email: mail@example.com
          default_author: github_actor
          message: 'Update unified config file'
          push: true
```